# Selenium internet explorer click function not working properly

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, click, webdriver

So i am using the click function from selenium and it return succeed, but it didnt happen, my code looks like this

*`m_Selenium.click(p_TestData.m_saData[TestData.OBJECT]);`*
p_TestData.m_saData[TestData.OBJECT] can look like  link=something, or css=something...

i know there has been a lot of topic about this already, but i tried all of them and the only one that worked was 
*`m_Driver.findElement(By.xpath(object)).sendKeys("\n");`*

but the problem is that i have a lot of test using different By value, and i dont like nested if\else.

so i tried the zoom 
*`DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);

m_Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);`*

i tried the set all the security setting in IE to the same value.

so i would like to know if there are better option? my code is working fine on FF, chrome, safari, but doesnt work on IE. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons the IE driver may not click properly. By default, the IE driver uses so-called "native events" to click on elements. For a discussion of the history of native events and some of their potential problems, you can read [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) or watch [this video](http://youtube.com/watch?feature=plcp&v=myffo8o67OA) of a presentation from the 2012 Selenium Conference. As a workaround, you could try turning off native events, though that comes with its own sets of challenges.